# jsTree search plugin and special chars

Tags: jquery, jstree, jstree-search

I have nodes with special chars like ą š ų ū and if I search for uxx it will NOT return ūxx or ųxxx, search plugn match exact match, how to change that?

Current code snippet for searching:

```
$('#tree_search').keyup(function(){

        if(to) { clearTimeout(to); }

        to = setTimeout(function () {
            var v = $('#tree_search').val();
            $('#tree-wrap').jstree(false).search(v);
        },250);

    });
```

UPDATE: so I manage to insert callback function but in this function **only last element of array** working as expected ė == e so I think this is for loop issue but can't figure out what exactly...

```
var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [
{'base':'z','letters':/[\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763]/g},
{'base':'e', 'letters':/[\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD]/g}
];

var tempSearchString;

for( var i = 0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap.length; i++ ) {
    tempSearchString = searchString.replace(defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].letters, defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].base).toLowerCase();
}

var text = node.text;

for( var i = 0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap.length; i++ ) {
    text = (node.text || '').replace(defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].letters, defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].base).toLowerCase();
}

return ((text || '').indexOf(tempSearchString) != -1)
```

Comment: Try the `(?iu)` modifier with your regex.

Comment: The problem is I don't really understand this plugin I just using it "as is" no idea where is regex for that part :/

Comment: The `var v` I suppose.

Comment: @Koshinae there is no regex involved here. `.search` is a jstree method

Comment: @edc65 Oops, my bad, wasn't listening carefully. Now I see that `search` is plain, not regex. I found something, like `search_callback` for jsTree search plugin: https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.search.search_callback 

You could do somehting like `search_callback: function(str,node) { try{return node.text.match(new RegExp(str));} catch(ex){return false;}}`, where `str` will be the `search`'s first parameter, node is a jstree node, a sit iterates through each and every one, while searching.
Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/cr5DGpIU07I

Comment: @Koshinae still... there is no regex involved here. The OP needs to search a plain text, just without difference between accented and plain letters. This link is pertinent: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/1328

Comment: But he _needs_ to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the link will try do something in callback I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what i use in my code to escape accents (Warning: huge diacritics array) :

```
search_callback : function(searchString, node) {
        var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [
            {'base':'A', 'letters':/[\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F]/g},
            {'base':'AA','letters':/[\uA732]/g},
            {'base':'AE','letters':/[\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2]/g},
            {'base':'AO','letters':/[\uA734]/g},
            {'base':'AU','letters':/[\uA736]/g},
            {'base':'AV','letters':/[\uA738\uA73A]/g},
            {'base':'AY','letters':/[\uA73C]/g},
            {'base':'B', 'letters':/[\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181]/g},
            {'base':'C', 'letters':/[\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E]/g},
            {'base':'D', 'letters':/[\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779]/g},
            {'base':'DZ','letters':/[\u01F1\u01C4]/g},
            {'base':'Dz','letters':/[\u01F2\u01C5]/g},
            {'base':'E', 'letters':/[\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E]/g},
            {'base':'F', 'letters':/[\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B]/g},
            {'base':'G', 'letters':/[\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E]/g},
            {'base':'H', 'letters':/[\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D]/g},
            {'base':'I', 'letters':/[\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197]/g},
            {'base':'J', 'letters':/[\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248]/g},
            {'base':'K', 'letters':/[\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2]/g},
            {'base':'L', 'letters':/[\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780]/g},
            {'base':'LJ','letters':/[\u01C7]/g},
            {'base':'Lj','letters':/[\u01C8]/g},
            {'base':'M', 'letters':/[\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C]/g},
            {'base':'N', 'letters':/[\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4]/g},
            {'base':'NJ','letters':/[\u01CA]/g},
            {'base':'Nj','letters':/[\u01CB]/g},
            {'base':'O', 'letters':/[\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C]/g},
            {'base':'OI','letters':/[\u01A2]/g},
            {'base':'OO','letters':/[\uA74E]/g},
            {'base':'OU','letters':/[\u0222]/g},
            {'base':'P', 'letters':/[\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754]/g},
            {'base':'Q', 'letters':/[\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A]/g},
            {'base':'R', 'letters':/[\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782]/g},
            {'base':'S', 'letters':/[\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784]/g},
            {'base':'T', 'letters':/[\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786]/g},
            {'base':'TZ','letters':/[\uA728]/g},
            {'base':'U', 'letters':/[\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244]/g},
            {'base':'V', 'letters':/[\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245]/g},
            {'base':'VY','letters':/[\uA760]/g},
            {'base':'W', 'letters':/[\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72]/g},
            {'base':'X', 'letters':/[\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C]/g},
            {'base':'Y', 'letters':/[\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE]/g},
            {'base':'Z', 'letters':/[\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762]/g},
            {'base':'a', 'letters':/[\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250]/g},
            {'base':'aa','letters':/[\uA733]/g},
            {'base':'ae','letters':/[\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3]/g},
            {'base':'ao','letters':/[\uA735]/g},
            {'base':'au','letters':/[\uA737]/g},
            {'base':'av','letters':/[\uA739\uA73B]/g},
            {'base':'ay','letters':/[\uA73D]/g},
            {'base':'b', 'letters':/[\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253]/g},
            {'base':'c', 'letters':/[\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184]/g},
            {'base':'d', 'letters':/[\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A]/g},
            {'base':'dz','letters':/[\u01F3\u01C6]/g},
            {'base':'e', 'letters':/[\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD]/g},
            {'base':'f', 'letters':/[\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C]/g},
            {'base':'g', 'letters':/[\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F]/g},
            {'base':'h', 'letters':/[\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265]/g},
            {'base':'hv','letters':/[\u0195]/g},
            {'base':'i', 'letters':/[\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131]/g},
            {'base':'j', 'letters':/[\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249]/g},
            {'base':'k', 'letters':/[\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3]/g},
            {'base':'l', 'letters':/[\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747]/g},
            {'base':'lj','letters':/[\u01C9]/g},
            {'base':'m', 'letters':/[\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F]/g},
            {'base':'n', 'letters':/[\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5]/g},
            {'base':'nj','letters':/[\u01CC]/g},
            {'base':'o', 'letters':/[\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275]/g},
            {'base':'oi','letters':/[\u01A3]/g},
            {'base':'ou','letters':/[\u0223]/g},
            {'base':'oo','letters':/[\uA74F]/g},
            {'base':'p','letters':/[\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755]/g},
            {'base':'q','letters':/[\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759]/g},
            {'base':'r','letters':/[\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783]/g},
            {'base':'s','letters':/[\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B]/g},
            {'base':'t','letters':/[\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787]/g},
            {'base':'tz','letters':/[\uA729]/g},
            {'base':'u','letters':/[\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289]/g},
            {'base':'v','letters':/[\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C]/g},
            {'base':'vy','letters':/[\uA761]/g},
            {'base':'w','letters':/[\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73]/g},
            {'base':'x','letters':/[\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D]/g},
            {'base':'y','letters':/[\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF]/g},
            {'base':'z','letters':/[\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763]/g}
        ];
        var tempSearchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
        for(var i=0; i<defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap.length; i++) {
            tempSearchString = tempSearchString.replace(defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].letters, defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].base);
        }
        var text = (node.text || '').toLowerCase();
        for(var i=0; i<defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap.length; i++) {
            text = text.replace(defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].letters, defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].base);
        }
        return text.indexOf(tempSearchString) != -1;

    }
```

A bit of an explanation:

The search_callback is called on every node of the jsTree and the node itself is passed as an argument to the function.

We loop through the search text string to remove the accents first and replace them with the *base*.

Then we do the same for the node text and finally we can easily compare them using nodeText.indexOf(searchString). If the searchString is not in the nodeText, it returns -1.

The .toLowerCase() is facultative. In my case, we wanted to ignore the capital letters too.

edit: Forgot to mention that tempSearchString was assigned with the seachString because we use the variable itself while looping to replace the accents with their matching base.

Answer (score 2):

Working solution:

```
"search" : {
            "show_only_matches" : true,
            "fuzzy" : false,
            "search_leaves_only" : true,
            search_callback: function(searchString, node) {

                var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [
                    {'base':'a', 'letters':/[\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250]/g},
                    {'base':'c', 'letters':/[\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184]/g},
                    {'base':'i', 'letters':/[\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131]/g},
                    {'base':'s', 'letters':/[\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B]/g},
                    {'base':'u', 'letters':/[\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289]/g},
                    {'base':'z', 'letters':/[\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763]/g},
                    {'base':'e', 'letters':/[\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD]/g}
                ];

                var tempSearchString;

                for( var i = 0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap.length; i++ ) {
                    tempSearchString = searchString.replace(defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].letters, defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].base).toLowerCase();
                }

                var text = node.text;

                for( var i = 0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap.length; i++ ) {
                    text = text.replace(defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].letters, defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].base).toLowerCase();
                }

                return ((text || '').indexOf(tempSearchString) != -1)

            }
        },
```

Comment: For the first `replace`, it should be `tempSearchString.replace`, with the `tempSearchString` declaration as `var tempSearchString = searchString;`. As it is, accents aren't removed from the **searched string**, only those on the letter '**e**'.